# Style material-ui tooltip using @emotion/styled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

Is it possible to style material-ui tooltips using the styled function from @emotion/styled?

```
import { Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const MyTooltip = styled(Tooltip)`
    // style the tooltip label
`
```

I tried using the global Mui classes etc. but did not succeed.
I know that an option is to use `createMuiTheme` and use `<ThemeProvider>` to apply it, but then the default theme is also applied to the children of the Tooltip component.

Answer (score 6):

The difficulty with styling `Tooltip` in this manner is that `Tooltip` doesn't support a `className` prop (which is what the `styled` function injects) -- the `className` prop would simply be forwarded on to the element wrapped by the tooltip.

The solution is to intercept the props passed by `styled` and leverage the `classes` prop of `Tooltip` as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const StyledTooltip = styled(({ className, ...other }) => (
  <Tooltip classes={{ tooltip: className }} {...other} />
))`
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <StyledTooltip title="Test tooltip">
        <span>Hover over me</span>
      </StyledTooltip>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit emotion/styled Tooltip]

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11467